# JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE even though it points to a JDK

Tags: java, linux, maven

Hello and thank you for any help you can provide.

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04.1 and before the install my JAVA_HOME for my path was defined properly and worked successfully. However, I am now unable to use Maven due to the following error: `"JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE"`. I know this is a common problem and I tried a lot of potential solutions before making this post.

When I `echo $JAVA_HOME`, I get back `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin` which is what I set it to be in my .bashrc via the following lines:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
export PATH
```

From there, I also checked `Which java` where I got the output of /usr/bin/java. I checked further and found that `readlink -f /usr/bin/java` returns a value of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`. Again, this points to a JDK not a JRE.

I also attempted to fix the issue by configuring a java with `sudo update-alternatives --config java` and chose the value of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`

To top it all off, I have reinstalled java and maven and I have restarted my computer and command line multiple times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, try and remove the `/bin` from your `JAVA_HOME` path.

You should reference the main folder of the JDK, not its `bin/` subfolder.

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you. I read on one of the other posts to reference /bin. The main folder makes a lot more sense

Comment: Which one?  There are a lot of incorrect answers in StackOverflow, but the unless someone points them out, we can't "stomp" them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619545/how-to-correct-java-home-which-should-point-to-a-jdk-not-a-jre-folder This was the post. However a correct answer wasn't selected so it definitely lowered the chance of that being right in the first place (its method 2 of the 2nd post)